# Performing a subquery using values from a column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I'm trying to create a calculated column in SQL.  Basically I need to get a set of distinct dates and determine how many customers there are in the population on that particular date. The result should be something like:

> Date______| Customers
>
> 2016-01-01 | 1
>
> 2016-01-01 | 2
>
> 2016-01-05 | 3
>
> 2016-02-09 | 4
>
> etc.

I created a sample database & data (using MySQL as I don't have permission to create tables in our Oracle dbs) with the following script:

```
create database customer_example;
use customer_example;

create table customers (
customer_id int not null primary key,
customer_name varchar(255) not null,
term_date DATE);

create table employee (
employee_id int not null primary key,
employee_name varchar(255) not null);

create table cust_emp (
ce_id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
emp_id int not null,
cust_id int not null,
start_date date,
end_date date,
deleted_yn boolean,
primary key (emp_id, cust_id, ce_id),
foreign key (cust_id) references customers(customer_id),
foreign key (emp_id) references employee(employee_id));


insert into customers (customer_id, customer_name)
values (1, 'Bobby Tables'), (2, 'Grover Cleveland'), (3, 'Chester Arthur'), (4, 'Jan Bush'), (5, 'Emanuel Porter'), (6, 'Darren King'), (7, 'Casey Mcguire'), (8, 'Robin Simpson'), (9, 'Robin Tables'), (10, 'Mitchell Arnold');

insert into customers (customer_id, customer_name, term_date)
values (11, 'Terrell Graves', '2017-01-01'), (12, 'Richard Wagner', '2016-10-31'), (13, 'Glenn Saunders', '2016-11-19'), (14, 'Bruce Irvin', '2016-03-11'), (15, 'Glenn Perry','2016-06-06'), (16, 'Hazel Freeman', '2016-07-10'), 
(17, 'Martin Freeman', '2016-02-11'), (18, 'Morgan Freeman', '2017-02-01'), (19, 'Dirk Drake', '2017-01-12'), (20, 'Fraud Fraud', '2016-12-31');

insert into employee (employee_id, employee_name)
values (1000, 'Cedrick French'), (1001, 'Jane Phillips'), (1002, 'Brian Green'), (1003, 'Shawn Brooks'), (1004, 'Clarence Thomas');

insert into cust_emp (emp_id, cust_id, start_date, end_date)
values (1000, 1, '2016-01-01', '2016-02-01'), (1000, 1, '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01'), (1000, 2,'2016-01-05', '2016-01-16'),(1000, 3,'2016-02-09', '2016-03-14'),(1000, 4,'2016-03-20', '2016-04-23'),
(1000, 5,'2016-01-01', '2016-01-16'),(1000, 6,'2016-01-01', '2016-01-16'),(1004, 7, '2016-01-14', '206-01-16'),
(1004, 8, '2016-01-13', '2016-01-16'),(1004, 9, '2016-01-05', '2016-01-16'), (1003, 12, '2016-04-21', '2016-11-30');

insert into cust_emp (emp_id, cust_id, start_date, deleted_yn)
values (1002, 11, '2016-04-10', TRUE),(1003, 10, '2016-01-16', FALSE), (1004, 12, '2016-04-20', TRUE), (1004, 12, '2016-04-19', FALSE), (1003, 13, '2016-06-06', TRUE), (1002, 14, '2016-06-10', TRUE),
(1004, 15, '2016-03-25', TRUE), (1004, 17, '2016-01-02', TRUE), (1004, 18, '2017-01-01', TRUE), (1004, 19, '2016-11-13', TRUE), (1004, 20, '2016-03-10', TRUE), (1004, 16, '2016-05-13', TRUE);


insert into cust_emp (emp_id, cust_id, start_date)
values (1002, 1, '2016-02-01'), (1004, 2, '2016-01-16'),(1003, 3, '2016-03-14'),(1002, 4, '2016-04-23'),(1004, 5, '2016-01-16'),(1002, 6, '2016-01-16'),(1004, 7, '2016-01-16'),
(1004, 8, '2016-01-16'),(1002, 9, '2016-01-16'), (1004, 10, '2016-01-16');
```

The following SQL works fine in MySQL but when I try it in Oracle, I get an 'invalid identifier' on 'dates':

```
select distinct(ce.start_date) as dates,
(select count(distinct(c.customer_id)) 
from customers c
    inner join cust_emp ce on c.customer_id = ce.cust_id
where ce.start_date < dates
    and (ce.end_date > dates or (ce.deleted_yn = false or ce.deleted_yn is null))
    and (c.term_date > dates or c.term_date is null)
)
from cust_emp as ce;
```

It seems as though this is because the dates is too far in a subquery. I've tried a CTE as well, but that seems to have the same issue as it gave the same error. How can I re-write this so that I can assess how many customers were there for each date in Oracle?

Comment: There is no way that the above query worked in mysql. it has errors.

Comment: @Gordon - Not for me. http://rextester.com/LAYQ25831 there is no dates column in cust_emp

Comment: Now try making the same changes and running in the oracle too.

Comment: I fixed that on my editor but forgot to copy over the change when it. Should work now.

Comment: that was the only error you had. it should now work in oracle too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh?

Isn't this what you want?

```
select ce.dates as dates, count(distinct c.customer_id) 
from cust_emp ce join
     customers c
     on c.customer_id = ce.cust_id
where ce.start_date < ce.dates and
      (ce.end_date > ce.dates or ce.deleted_yn = false or ce.deleted_yn is null) and
      (c.term_date > ce.dates or c.term_date is null)
group by ce.dates
order by ce.dates;
```

I don't really understand the use of the subquery with `select distinct`.  The logic you describe is more easily understood as a simple aggregation.

I'm not sure where `dates` comes from.  It is not in your data model, but it is in your sample query.

Comment: dates was a typo, should be start_date. This makes much more sense than I came up with; will try in a second here.

Comment: There is no dates column in the cust_emp table and if you change it to start_date as OP says, it will not make any sense.

Comment: Ah, I see why it didn't make any sense. It didn't occurr to me because the sample had such a small set. When I ran this on the actual data it comes back with a very small set per date. The reason for my original sub query was so that I could get all of the customer_ids that occurred *before* the start date (so that I could determine how many total customers there were prior to midnight of that date). If I'm not mistaken, this gives me how many customers have that particular start date.